# Empty code coverage

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, codeception

I'm trying to get code coverage for my unit tests with codeception.

When i'm doing `vendor/bin/codecept run unit --coverage` it displays that :

```
  Classes:  0.00% (0/1) 
  Methods:  0.00% (0/3) 
  Lines:    0.00% (0/28)
```

Although I have tested 1 method over 3.

I have xdebug installed with `coverage_enable=On`

Here is my codeception.yml config file :

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: ''
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
coverage:
    enable: true
    remote: false
    include:
        - Simplifier/*
    exclude:
        - vendor/*
```

I'm trying to test Simplifier/Routing.php

The test is OK, but my coverage is wrong.

Any idea why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake in setting name.

Change `enable: true` to `enabled: true` and code coverage collection will work.
http://codeception.com/docs/11-Codecoverage#Configuration

Comment: It had to come back 3 times to this answer to finally recognize what the difference is.